# Why my onClick event not firing on image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am developing app for android. but my img click function is not firing. Don't know why. The same works for div, but not for img. Any ideas why?

This is html code:

```
<img src="talk.png" id="talk" class="thumb3"/>
```

This is jQuery:

```
$("#talk").on('vclick', function () {
            alert("ItWorks!");                                                      
});
```

This is CSS:

```
.thumb3 {
        width:40px;
        height: 40px;
        margin-top:5px;
        z-index:999;
}
```

**EDIT**
tried with `click` and still not working.

Comment: @Satpal on touch devices(Phone) it is vclick event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Someone before me was inserted a div over the whole item with transparent background, so I removed the div and it worked fine. Don't know why would someone do that. This is why I don't like working on other people projects.

Answer (score 2):

Use ready function:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#talk").on('vclick', function () {
            alert("ItWorks!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery Mobile "vclick" event handler simulates the "onclick" event handler on mobile devices. @Anoop

Comment: @anoop please don't change the content. just format it!!

Comment: @Mr_Green it was his initial solution. I didnt change any of the content. May be after copying for the formatting, he should have changed to vclick again..

Answer (score 1):

you have an typo error change vclick to click

```
$("#talk").on('click', function () {
        alert("ItWorks!");                                                      
});
```